# Extract numbers from txt file

Tags: windows-10

I have a big list in txt file of contact information. I need to grab the phone numbers from a structure like this:

[image: example]

I would need the output to be only with numbers in the text, for example:

- 4149611000
- 4143620851
- 3605966100
- 3096949898
- etc.

What command in the cmd could sort out this ?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1795520/edit) you question and add a sample of your file as text (not picture).

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr **`perl -lne 'print $1 while /(\d{10})/g' filenames.txt ...`**

---

```
$ cat n.txt
aaaa 0123456789 bbbb
apple banana cucumber
9876543210 ccc ccc ccc
ppp qqq 12345 rrr sss
```

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 if /(\d{10})/' n.txt
0123456789
9876543210
```

If there can be multiple phone numbers per line and you do want all of them:

```
$ echo double 1111111111 number 2222222222 here >> n.txt
$ perl -lne 'print $1 while /(\d{10})/g' n.txt
0123456789
9876543210
1111111111
2222222222
```

If the phone number is always the 5th comma-separated field you could use

```
$ perl -F, -lne 'print $F[4]' m.txt 
PHONE
1234567890
0987654321
```

Note perl has 0-based indexes (0,1,2 not 1,2,3)

Or use simpler tools:

```
$ cut -d, -f5 m.txt
PHONE
1234567890
0987654321
```

The above was done using WSL under Windows 10, but native Windows Perl is available for Windows 10 command prompt. Like this:

```
C> perl -lne "print $1 while /(\d{10})/g" n.txt
0123456789
9876543210
1111111111
2222222222
```

There's almost certainly a way to do this in powershell (though probably more typing)

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell, try the following cmdlets:

```ps
Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\yourfile.txt | Select-String "\d{10}" -AllMatches | ForEach {$_.Matches} | Select Value
```

OR

```ps
Select-String -Path "C:\path\to\yourfile.txt" -Pattern "\d{10}" -AllMatches | Select -ExpandProperty Matches | Select Value
```

This will display only 10-digit length numbers. If you want the output in a file:

```ps
Get-Content -Path C:\path\to\yourfile.txt | Select-String "\d{10}" -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches} | Select Value | Out-File output.txt
```